# Android JobIntentService permission error

Tags: android

I have created a JobIntentSerivce and in the manifest file for the MyService class I didn't specify the BIND_JOB_SERVICE permission. So while I enqueue work for this service it is throwing run time error "MyService does not require android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE permission". If I give the permission to MyService in android manifest it will fix the issue. But my doubt is why the error showing "does not require permission", is it a typo or any logical reason behind it?

Answer (score 0):

`JobIntentService` must be protected by `BIND_JOB_SERVICE` permission, but while adding permission in the manifest, setting `android:exported` to true will resolve this somewhat confusing error e.g

```
<service android:name="com.example.jobscheduler.MyService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:exported="true"/>
```

Comment: Question is, why the error says "does not require permission" which is misleading?

Comment: because you haven't exported it yet, hence no external component (e.g job-schedular) is able to launch it, thus no need to specify bind_job_service permission

Comment: @Qasim read the question, OP knows this, they are wondering on misleading error message, that is all.

Comment: yeah, that's what i mentioned in my last comment, error is not misleading, if you are not exporting your component to allow any 3rd party apps/components to launch/use your service, in that case, framework says, that "it doesn't require permission", thus when we declare exported=true, framework now mark our component ready to be used by any 3rd party component for which it requires `bind` permission.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense to throw a runtime error if it doesn't require the permission would you not agree?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source the comments on the method: `enforceValidJobRequest(int uid, JobInfo job)` in `JobSchedulerStub` does go some way to explain what it is checking :

JobSchedulerService.JobSchedulerStub :

`// Enforce that only the app itself (or shared uid participant) can schedule a
// job that runs one of the app's services, as well as verifying that the
// named service properly requires the BIND_JOB_SERVICE permission
private void enforceValidJobRequest(int uid, JobInfo job) { .. }`

Inside this method it definitely checks that the `Service` in `JobInfo` (`jobinfo.getService()`) has the permission `BIND_JOB_SERVICE` - if not throws the error, to me a somewhat misleading message.  It Also checks that only the system or app uid can enqueue work, this is obviously for security reasons.